# django - setting a non-nullable field in pre_save

Tags: django, django-orm, django-signals

I'm trying to set a non nullable OneToOneField object (which hasn't been set) in the `pre_save` method.

```
class A(Model):
    b = models.OneToOneField(B, on_delete=CASCADE)

    @staticmethod
    def pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance.b
        except RelatedObjectDoesNotExist:
            instance.b = B()
            instance.b.save()

pre_save.connect(A.pre_save, A)
```

Even though the B object gets created and stored in the database, I get this error as if the A object doesn't point to B

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_a.b_id`

If I set `null=True` in the field definition, of course I don't get the `NOT NULL constraint failed` error. But still, the A object doesn't store the reference to the B object.

I'm guessing this is because in the original A object there is no B reference, so when save is executed somehow it doesn't think it should save the b property.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Seem like you want to create a reference to B when A just created right? So I think you can set it to Nullable, and create a reference to B by pre_save signal

Comment: I already tried that as stated in the last part of the question

Comment: instance.b, this won't raise any error when you set the field to be nullable. try `if not instance.b: #Create new B` instead.

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that I create the new B `if not instance.b: instance.b = B()` but after saving the `.b` property is still `None` (althouth the B got created)

Comment: Have you called `instance.save()` this one will commit all changes on instance.

Comment: call `instance.save()` inside the `pre_save` method?

Comment: Oh yeah, `pre_save`, I don't think we need to call `instance.save()`. It should save the reference @@

Comment: Hi guys, I found the source of the problem, thanks everyone for thinking this with me

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the source of the problem!

This error happens when you assign the object before saving it. If you save the object and assign it later, it saves the object correctly:

```
b = B()
b.save()
instance.b = b
```